# Is there explanation for mentioned code are available?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Could you please share me the explanation for below mentioned codes. As I'm not able to understand these code by my own. I'm assumimg that this is defnine function for column but not sure about.

```
def remove_common_text(lst):
    if len(lst) > 4:
            for itm in lst:
                if len(itm)>1:
                    rep = True
                    while rep == True:
                        ctr = 0
                        ctr2 = 0
                        for itm2 in lst:
                            if len(itm2)>0:
                                if itm[0] == itm2[0]:
                                    ctr = ctr + 1
                                if itm[-1] == itm2[-1]:
                                    ctr2 = ctr2 + 1
                        if ctr > 4:
                            str = itm[0]
                            for itm2 in lst:
                                if len(itm2)>0:
                                    if itm2[0] == str and len(itm2)>1:
                                        del itm2[0]
                        if ctr2 > 4:
                            str2 = itm[-1]
                            for itm2 in lst:
                                if len(itm2)>0:
                                    if itm2[-1] == str2 and len(itm2)>1:
                                        del itm2[-1]
                        if (ctr <= 4 and ctr2 <= 4) or len(itm)<=1: rep = False
    id_unique = documents['ID'].unique()
    print(id_unique)
    for id in id_unique:
        remove_common_text(documents[documents.ID==id]['split_clean'])
        print(id)
```

Comment: Do you know what it’s supposed to do, even if you don’t understand each step? If so you could write a unit test for it and see what it does.

Answer (score -1):

I am going to write what `remove_common_text(lst)` does. The stuff below is pandas, so perhaps someone else can answer it better than I can.

The parameter lst is supposed to be something like this: `[['a','b','c','d','e'],['a','b','1','d','e'],['a','b','2','d','e'],['a','b','3','d','e'],['a','b','4','d','e'], ['a','b','c','d','-1']]`.

Your python snippet works in 3 parts:

1. It counts the number of similar elements per "item" and records it as counter variables `ctr` & `ctr2`, **from the start and end of each "item".** Keep this bold part in mind as this is something exclusive here.
2. It deletes the similarity ctr recorded.
3. Then deletes the similarity ctr2 recorded.

**Exclusive part:** It checks from start and end, so if you throw "abcde" & "a1bcd2e" at it. It will stop checking at 1 & 2 even if "bcd" elemnets are common.

If you are wondering, for above case, it gives `[['c'], ['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['c', 'd', '-1']]`

And one more test case:
I/O: `[['a','b','c','d','e'],['a','b','1','d','e','j'],['a','b','2','d','e'],['a','b','3','d','e'],['a','b','4','d','e'], ['a','b','c','d','e']]`

O/P: `[['c'], ['1', 'd', 'e', 'j'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['c']]`